# Why do Chrome and Windows report a different file size?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer, filesystems

I'm working on bundling and minification for an web app I'm working on and I noticed Windows and Chrome report significantly different sizes for the same file.

Why do Chrome and Windows see this file as different sizes? And how big is the file really?

Windows reports it as about 45KB:
[image]

In the properties window:

[image]

In the Network tab on Chrome the size is 10.5KB:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the Network tab in Chrome doesn't show the file size, but the size of network traffic used for downloading that file. (Because loading a random webpage gives me "(from memory cache)" in the size column.)

Windows however shows the actual file size required to store the given file, which is in most of the cases bigger than the network traffic, considering that most [HTTP traffic is compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Comment: I bet you're right, I wasn't thinking about compression.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not the size of network traffic (transfer size) as you suggest, but the uncompressed size vs. compressed size. I wrote a longer explainer on it here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74648552/4002508